# password validation - python

Tags: python, validation, passwords

I am trying to make a code to validate a password. However it is not working, any ideas on how to fix this?

```
password = input("Please enter password: ")

length = False
digit = False
capital = False

length = len(password)

if length > 6:
    length = True
    #print("Length Good")

for count in password:
    if count.isdigit():
        digit = True
        #print ("Contains digit")

for count in password:
    if count.isupper():
        capital = True
        #print ("Contains a capital")

if length != True and digit != True and capital != True:
    print("Password is good")
else:
    print("Bad password")
```

any ideas on how to fix this, thanks

Comment: `length` cannot be the length of your password and *also* a true/false value. Use two variables.

Comment: (1) You can't use the same variable "length" for two purposes at the same time. (2) A password like "zgjf" is accepted as good.

Comment: Also, your code requires a "good" password to *not* contain a capital letter and *not* contain a digit. That seems unlikely to be what you intended.

Comment: @khelwood  I have changed the code but it still doesn't seem to work? thanks

Comment: @MichaelButscher  I have changed the code but it still doesn't seem to work? thanks

Comment: @khelwood, good you give me an example on how to correct the code please x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran it and entered "test" and it said "Password is good". I suspect you meant to have:

```py
password = input("Please enter password: ")

length = False
digit = False
capital = False

length = len(password)

if length > 6:
    length = True
    #print("Length Good")

for count in password:
    if count.isdigit():
        digit = True
        #print ("Contains digit")

for count in password:
    if count.isupper():
        capital = True
        #print ("Contains a capital")

if length == True and digit == True and capital == True:
    print("Password is good")
else:
    print("Bad password")
```

because otherwise you are enforcing bad passwords.

Comment: Cool, great @Katie010203 Can you mark this as the correct answer so I can get the points?

Comment: I will, it says I have to wait 1min thou x

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are assigning the length of your password to the variable `length`, and then promptly overwriting the value in `length` with `False`:

```
length = len(password)
length = False
```

Also, you be checking if `length`, `digit`, and `capital` are `True`, as checking them for `False` will give you opposite results unless you flip the statement

You should instead move `len(password)` to the check itself, like so:

```
password = input("Please enter password: ")

length = False
digit = False
capital = False

if len(password) > 6:
    length = True
    # print("Length Good")

for count in password:
    if count.isdigit():
         digit = True
         # print ("Contains digit")
    elif count.isupper():
         capital = True
         # print ("Contains a capital")

if length == True and digit == True and capital == True:
    print("Password is good")
else:
    print("Bad password")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the

```
length = len(password)
```

and after

```
length = False
```

so Python first set length like an int, and in the second instruction Python cancel the value of variable and set the length variable like a boolean(False) and the condition length>6 failed.

Answer (score 0):

Used Bitwise OR operator to validate the password.

Time complexity is **O(n)**.

```py
def validate(password):
    sum = 0
    if len(password) < 7:
        return False
    for p in password:
        if p.isdigit():
            sum |= 1    #2^0
        elif p.isupper():
            sum |= 2    #2^1
        # elif not p.isalnum():
        #     sum |= 4    #2^2

    if sum == 3:    # 2^n - 1 where n is the no. of conditions inside for loop
        return True
    else:
        return False

password = 'voteUp1IfUsefulAnswer'
result = validate(password)
if result:
    print("Password is good")
else:
    print("Bad password")
```